# Can I play League of Legends in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, games

I want to play League of Legends (LOL) on my laptop which runs Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any way to play that game on my Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Yes. If your laptop is powerful enough, just run it in a Windows VM.

Comment: Think LoL requires DirectX effects that are not available using Windows in a VM...

Comment: If you really want it to run on ubuntu natively. Please sign a petition for this at http://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/petition-port-league-of-legends-to-linux-operating-systems

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 4):

It seems this is possible. There's too much to post here, but there's a [lenghty tutorial, with videos](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=973373) on the LoL forums. This method uses Wine to run the game.

Comment: are there any video to show how to do that?can you please include the link?

Comment: @Asnawi7195 The videos are linked on that page.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to play LoL through the latest version of PlayOnLinux. Here's [a guide](http://linuxforcynics.com/how-to/how-to-install-and-play-league-of-legends-on-ubuntu) that explains how to set it up.

Summary: Install PlayOnLinux from their site (not through the Ubuntu repos, they are out of date), enable Testing in PlayOnLinux, then search for and install LoL through PoL. For more details, check the link above.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

tested on UBUNTU 12.04 LTS version with  non installed lol client just copying pasteing lol folder games

1. Install Winetricks from Software Manager
2. Run the following in terminal:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.5
3. Run the following in terminal:
   winetricks vcrun2005
   winetricks ie8
   winetricks wininet
   winetricks d3dx9
   winetricks corefonts
   winetricks adobeair

completely with some fix and tweak check at mah blog
http://warnetkid.blogspot.com/2013/05/playing-league-of-legends-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

I just re-installed LoL on PlayOnLinux in August 2014, and the game is working very well.  You MUST use PlayOnLinux to install the game, otherwise there is a lengthy and error-prone 12-step process to get it working; the game needs a very special (1.7.x) version of Wine to work properly, and special libraries, and some special tweaks, to work properly.  PlayOnLinux will automatically set up the entire environment for you.

Problems displaying icons in the magic store have been fixed.

I have had only 1 problem - I cannot play on my 1920x1200 external Dell IPS monitor (2412U).  The game does not start properly when I am running in dual-display mode.  Because my external monitor is 16:10 and my laptop is 16:9, I get a very low resolution (maybe 1280x800) if I try running in mirrored mode, so it's not worth trying to run the game on the external monitor (my laptop is 1600x900).